# I added a CSS animation but it doesn't work and everything looks fine

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

So I tried to add a simple vibration animation to a link from my website but it simply doesn't work. Anyone see anything wrong with my code?

I took the animation code from animista.net and there they were working

Here is my code:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  animation: vibrate 1s linear infinite both;
}

@keyframes vibrate {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-2px, 2px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(2px, 2px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(2px, -2px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:me@eduardstefan.com" id="cta">Drop me a line and let’s do cool things together!</a>
```

Comment: `a`nchors are `inline`. Make that `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `position: absolute` or change `display` value to block-level *(because `a` is `inline` by default)* for `transform` to work.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block; /* Or inline-block */
  animation: vibrate 1s linear infinite both;
}

@keyframes vibrate {
  0% { transform: translate(0); }
  20% { transform: translate(-2px, 2px); }
  40% { transform: translate(-2px, -2px); }
  60% { transform: translate(2px, 2px); }
  80% { transform: translate(2px, -2px); }
  100% { transform: translate(0); }
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:me@eduardstefan.com" id="cta">Drop me a line and let’s do cool things together!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS animation is not used to target anchor.
so please use div for easy animation effects

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.div {
  text-decoration: none;
  position:relative;
   animation:vibrate 1s linear infinite both;
}

@keyframes vibrate {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0,0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-2px, 2px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(2px, 2px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(2px, -2px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div">
<a href="mailto:me@eduardstefan.com" id="cta">Drop me a line and let’s do cool things together!</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```